# How to make all blocks of the same width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to make blocks of the same width? It is necessary that the blocks fill the entire width of the screen, and started from the left edge.

It turns out only that the last block occupies the entire width. 
The last seventh block should not fill the entire width, it should be like the first six, while it should be responsive. I need to use only flexbox, media queries and scripts will not work for me.

=

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
      
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #000000;
}
      
header,
footer {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
}
      
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
      
li {
  width: 350px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #1b6351;        
}
      
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
   flex: 1 0 auto;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <header>top</header>
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <footer>bottom</footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question? everything appears to be working correctly

Comment: ohh i see the problem now after opening up in full screen

Comment: I have a video of the kind of how it should look: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L8fNpkKOAhU48CbkwczmlAVxJMKTck3p/view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42767664/flex-wrapped-items-with-same-width-as-the-rest/42767892#42767892 Just one out of many duplicate questions.

Comment: This option is not suitable if the screen width is 100%

Comment: have you try with css grid. its far easy than flex

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question properly, you are just missing `flex-basis: 100%;` on the `li`.

See working example here https://codepen.io/Angel-SG/pen/aPBrje

Hope that helps!

Comment: Not really, it should look like this. The last seventh block should be as wide as the first six. Look in full screen please

Comment: Ups sorry, I just amended the code pen, have a look!

Comment: I have a video of the kind of how it should look: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L8fNpkKOAhU48CbkwczmlAVxJMKTck3p/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Thing is you should add equal/ min-width to each media query for your desired result. I have styled a little and added media query.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
      
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
      
header,
footer {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
}
      
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 5px;
}
      
li {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  min-width: 20%;
}
li > div{
  display:block;
  background:#cdcdcd;
  text-align:center;
  padding:15px;
  border-radius:3px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
   flex: 1 0 auto;
  background:#fefefe;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

@media (max-width:1200px){
  ul li{
    min-width:25%;
  }
}

@media (max-width:1024px){
  ul li{
    min-width:33.33%;
  }
}

@media (max-width:768px){
  ul li{
    min-width:50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width:540px){
  ul li{
    min-width:100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <header>Header</header>
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><div>1</div></li>
        <li><div>2</div></li>
        <li><div>3</div></li>
        <li><div>4</div></li>
        <li><div>5</div></li>
        <li><div>6</div></li>
        <li><div>7</div></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help for you!

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
      
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #000000;
}
      
header,
footer {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
}
      
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
      
li {
    /* width: 350px; */
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #1b6351;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 350px;    
}
      
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
   flex: 1 0 auto;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
    <header>top</header>
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <footer>bottom</footer>
    </div>
```