# CSS: find items in last row using flex layout [not a duplicate]

Tags: css

I am using media queries and flex layout to display my items in a container.

It can be 1 column display or 2 columns or 3 columns or 4 columns or 5 columns or 6 columns depending on the screen size.

For example:

```
<div class="containter">
   <item>item1<item>
   <item>item2<item>
   <item>item3<item>
   <item>item4<item>
   <item>item5<item>
</div>
```

If the display is 2 columns, I would like to target only

```
<item>item5<item>
```

And if,

```
<div class="containter">
   <item>item1<item>
   <item>item2<item>
   <item>item3<item>
   <item>item4<item>
   <item>item5<item>
   <item>item6<item>
</div>
```

If the display is 2 columns, I would like to target both

```
<item>item5<item> 
<item>item6<item>
```

If the display is 3 columns, I would like to target 3 items

```
<item>item4<item>
<item>item5<item> 
<item>item6<item>
```

Is there a CSS selector to target items in the last row?

I was hoping to find the first item in the last row and then find siblings using ~ selector, but cant seem to get one working.

Update:
** Not a duplicate of 
[Targeting flex items on the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176419/targeting-flex-items-on-the-last-row)
since this link doesn't provide any solution. I am looking for some solution.

Comment: Are these going to be a set amount of items or are they going to be dynamically added?

Comment: These items are dynamically added.  I do not know the count of total items upfront.

Comment: Why is my question marked as duplicate and why other comments have been removed?

Comment: I am really looking for some solution and not able to remove [Duplicate] from the title.  Please look at the update and remove the tag [Duplicate]

Comment: As indicated in the duplicate, the current iteration of flexbox provides no solution to this problem. Even CSS in general has no clean solution. But the answer in the duplicate provides a long list of posts identical or nearly identical to yours. Many contain hacks that may work for you.