# Make CSS Grid auto-fill only 2 columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am using CSS Grid and have made the following layout in the codepen found here: https://codepen.io/alexg2195/pen/xLEeMd

My issue is that when using `repeat(auto-fill, minmax(400px, 1fr));` I end up with a layout that goes beyond just two columns.

Is there a way to force two columns but still have the same min auto fill resize behaviors?

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 100px;
  grid-template-areas: "main btn" "main .";
}

.btn {
  grid-area: btn;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.boxes {
  grid-area: main;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(400px, 1fr));
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="box a">A</div>
    <div class="box b">B</div>
    <div class="box c">C</div>
    <div class="box d">D</div>
    <div class="box e">E</div>
    <div class="box f">F</div>
    <div class="box g">G</div>
    <div class="box h">H</div>
    <div class="box i">I</div>
    <div class="box j">J</div>
    <div class="box k">K</div>
    <div class="box l">L</div>
    <div class="box m">M</div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">BTN</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to force two columns but still have the same min auto fill resize behaviors?

Not with `auto-fill` / `auto-fit`.

These functions are built to fit the largest number of tracks without overflowing the container.

> [**7.2.2.2. Repeat-to-fill: `auto-fill` and `auto-fit`
>   repetitions**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-repeat)
>
> When `auto-fill` is given as the repetition number, if the grid
>   container has a definite size or max size in the relevant axis, then
>   the number of repetitions is the *largest possible positive integer
>   that does not cause the grid to overflow its grid container*.

In order to "auto-fill" a maximum of two columns per row, you'll need to find another method.

Maybe flexbox?

[revised demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PKGrJW?editors=1100)

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 100px;
  grid-template-areas: "main btn" "main .";
}

.btn {
  grid-area: btn;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.boxes {
  grid-area: main;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  flex: 1 0 40%;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

div.box.n {
  visibility: hidden;    /* https://stackoverflow.com/q/42176419/3597276 */
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="box a">A</div>
    <div class="box b">B</div>
    <div class="box c">C</div>
    <div class="box d">D</div>
    <div class="box e">E</div>
    <div class="box f">F</div>
    <div class="box g">G</div>
    <div class="box h">H</div>
    <div class="box i">I</div>
    <div class="box j">J</div>
    <div class="box k">K</div>
    <div class="box l">L</div>
    <div class="box m">M</div>
    <div class="box n">N</div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">BTN</div>
</div>
```