# CSS spacing between span elements only when they are on the same line

Tags: css

I have a set of spans, each of which has "white-space: nowrap" to keep them individually non-breaking.  I want them to have some visual spacing separating them if they are next to each other on a line, but if the browser decides to line-break, I don't need or want left or right margins at the ends of the lines.

For example:

```
<div class="container">
   <span id="s1">User Option 1</span>
   <span id="s2">User Option 2</span>
   <span id="s3">User Option 3</span>
   <span id="s4">User Option 4</span>
   <span id="s5">User Option 5</span>
   <span id="s6">User Option 6</span>
   <span id="s7">User Option 7</span>
   <span id="s8">User Option 8</span>
</div>
```

In a wide window, I would like to see:

```
User Option 1 ________ User Option 2 ________ User Option 3 ________ User Option 4
User Option 5 ________ User Option 6 ________ User Option 7 ________ User Option 8
```

(I have supplied underscore characters to show where I would like some space/padding/margin.  I don't want to see the underscores, I want some spacing there.)

But I want the spacing only as needed, and for it to continue to behave nicely when the set of items wraps at different points.  So, if the window is somewhat narrower:

```
User Option 1 ________ User Option 2 ________ User Option 3
User Option 4 ________ User Option 5 ________ User Option 6
User Option 7 ________ User Option 8
```

Or narrower still:

```
User Option 1 ________ User Option 2
User Option 3 ________ User Option 4
User Option 5 ________ User Option 6
User Option 7 ________ User Option 8
```

I know if I just give everything a margin-left, then there is unwanted space reserved at the left of everything:

```
________ User Option 1 ________ User Option 2 ________ User Option 3
________ User Option 4 ________ User Option 5 ________ User Option 6
________ User Option 7 ________ User Option 8
```

If I give margin-left within a :not:first-child selector, it actually looks a bit worse:

```
User Option 1 ________ User Option 2 ________ User Option 3
________ User Option 4 ________ User Option 5 ________ User Option 6
________ User Option 7 ________ User Option 8
```

If I switch to right-margin, everything always looks good:

```
User Option 1 ________ User Option 2 ________ User Option 3 ________
User Option 4 ________ User Option 5 ________ User Option 6 ________
User Option 7 ________ User Option 8 ________
```

because you don't see the right margins that are unneeded.

But there is still a cause for complaint in that these elements are reserving that space off to the right and they therefore will "word-wrap" sooner than necessary because of it, so they still have the unwanted feature of wasting space to the right.

Is there something in CSS that really says what I want to say?

Colloquially, I would say: "margin-right-if-sibling-rendered-to-my-right" ?

Comment: I agree with @Highdef , this is a link I use all the time: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: instead of :not:first-child you may use :nth-child(4n+0) to select every fourth element.

Answer (score 2):

The margin space / wrapping problem has been solved by CSS Grid.

You create separation between grid items using the following properties:

- `grid-row-gap`
- `grid-column-gap`
- `grid--gap` (the shorthand for both properties above)

These properties create space between items, but never between items and the container.

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xsakoquc/1/)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

span {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span id="s1">User Option 1</span>
  <span id="s2">User Option 2</span>
  <span id="s3">User Option 3</span>
  <span id="s4">User Option 4</span>
  <span id="s5">User Option 5</span>
  <span id="s6">User Option 6</span>
  <span id="s7">User Option 7</span>
  <span id="s8">User Option 8</span>
</div>
```

Then, if you want space between the container and the items, add padding to the container.

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xsakoquc/2/)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;  /* added */
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

span {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span id="s1">User Option 1</span>
  <span id="s2">User Option 2</span>
  <span id="s3">User Option 3</span>
  <span id="s4">User Option 4</span>
  <span id="s5">User Option 5</span>
  <span id="s6">User Option 6</span>
  <span id="s7">User Option 7</span>
  <span id="s8">User Option 8</span>
</div>
```

More details here:

- [Removing margin from flex items when they wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46765533/3597276)
- [Equal width flex items even after they wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44154580/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

I think for the *particular layout* described, using **CSS Grid** is way more suitable than flexbox. Let's take a look at how it renders the layout:

- We make the **parent container** *(grid-container)* have the `display:grid` property.
- We `justify the contents` using `space-between` so the grid items are at their extremities (Unlike *flexbox* the grid-item doesn't float to the extreme right when space is available).
- We define the template columns with a **fixed width** after which it will wrap down to the next row.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 300px);
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-container>* {
  background-color: gray;
  color:white;
  border:2px solid black;
  margin:2px 0px 2px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
   <span id="s1">User Option 1</span>
   <span id="s2">User Option 2</span>
   <span id="s3">User Option 3</span>
   <span id="s4">User Option 4</span>
   <span id="s5">User Option 5</span>
   <span id="s6">User Option 6</span>
   <span id="s7">User Option 7</span>
   <span id="s8">User Option 8</span>
</div>
```

Comment: How can you allow each span to stretch to the width of its parent if e.g. the text is in one span does not wrap and therefore occupies a maximum width of the parent? In your example, no matter how much text a span contains, it will never stretch