# Flex layout and spacing between child divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent div with display:flex and multiple child divs as shown below. Also the flex-wrap is wrap on the container.

```
div1 div2 div3 div4
div5 div6 div7
```

My question is how do I ensure spacing between the 2 rows of divs i.e. top & bottom divs (So, in this case, between div1/div5 OR div2/div6 OR div3/div7)

Also, this is actually totally dynamic i.e. if there is more horizontal space available, my div5 might get rendered on the first row itself.

Just to add, currently I have a margin-top defined on all the child divs. However, that also gives margin-top on div1/div2/div3/div4
What I really want is only margin-top on divs which get rendered dynamically from the 2nd row ownwards ?

Hope I am able to explain the exact issue.

Comment: use `align-content: flex-start` property and then use `margin-bottom` for the *flex items*?

Comment: @testndtv - I think `flex-direction: column` and `justify-content` should set it up correctly. Can you share the relevant code you have worked on?

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46765935/2427237

Comment: Flexbox isn't well-suited for this task. Try CSS Grid: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46775239/3597276