# Prevent last item from stretching to fill the container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't work out why the last item stretches to fill the width of the container, how can I change things so that it only fills 50% like the others?

```css
.container {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
    flex: 50%;
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    Item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You are sizing your flex items using the [**`flex`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) shorthand property.

This property takes three values:

- `flex-grow`
- `flex-shrink`
- `flex-basis`

*The key point to understand is that omitting values in the `flex` property doesn't actually remove those values, it activates fallback values.*

You have `flex: 50%`.

That rule omits `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink`.

As defined in the [flexbox specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-flex-grow), when omitted in the `flex` property, `flex-grow` defaults to `1` and `flex-shrink` defaults to `1`.

So `flex: 50%` is equivalent to `flex: 1 1 50%`. That's why your last item consumes all free space.

Here are two solutions to the problem:

1. Replace `flex: 50%` with `flex-basis: 50%`. This leaves the `flex-grow` property at its [standard default setting, which is `0`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-grow-property).

OR

2. Replace `flex: 50%` with `flex: 0 0 50%`, which overrides any default `flex` property settings.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```