# Shrink grid items just like flex items in css

Tags: css, flexbox, grid-layout, css-grid

Is it possible to shrink grid items just like flex items in css?

**Grid items**

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid #a07;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oobarbazanoo/76uedo40/824/)

**Flex items**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: -10px;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid #a07;
  flex: 200px 1 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oobarbazanoo/76uedo40/831/)

In a nutshell I can have the following positioning of the elements with the flex above:

[image]

While I can not achieve the same behaviour by using a grid layout. Flex layout allows items to shrink on small screen, while grid layout does not allow. At the same time I would like to preserve the behavior that the item will move to the next line with another item only when after such a placement each one of them will be no shorter than a specific size (200px in our case).

I am using grid layout because it allows to preserve the invariant that widths of all the children will be the same. With flex layout the last item will be stretched to the whole line if it will be alone on the line.

Comment: Great question. It doesn't look possible with the current version of grid, as the `minmax()` function defines the actual minimum width of the track. This post may be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42176419/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B, thank you. Checked everything in the question provided. Will be waiting for the solution to my question appear. ( :

Comment: @Michael_B there is, let's say, a pseudo solution :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**New solution**

An optimized version of the initial solution using `min()`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min(200px,100%), 1fr));
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid #a07;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

**Old solution**

One solution is to specify a `max-width` to the child element relying on the viewport unit since percentage values are relative to the size of the track defined by the `minmax()` and cannot be used. This solution isn't generic and you need to adjust the value depending on each situation.

In you case for example, we can use `100vw` since the container is the only element in the body and is taking the whole width:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid #a07;
  max-width:100vw;
  box-sizing:border-box; /* Don't forget this !*/
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

In case there is more element or some padding/margin you need to consider them within the `max-width` calculation:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid #a07;
  max-width:calc(100vw - 40px); /*we remove the body margin*/
  box-sizing:border-box; 
}

body {
  margin:0 20px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

It's like we no more have 2 constraints but 3:

- The grid cell has a minimum size of `200px`
- The grid cell fill the remain space
- The element inside the grid cell has a maximum size defined relatively to the screen size. *(the shrink constraint we were missing)*