# CSS Grid Template Columns Repeat No More Than X Times

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a layout in which multiple items will be aligned in a grid. Let's use the following as an example:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.grid-item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
</div>
```

In the above code, the grid will repeat 3 columns per row and each item will expand to 1/3 of the row width. The problem is that in a responsive situation, the grid will always repeat 3 columns.

If I change the `repeat` value to `auto-fit` and adjust the column sizing to use `minmax` I can control how the page scales down and reduce the col width and count to some sane value. So adjusted code would look something like this:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px,1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.grid-item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
</div>
```

This works well scaling down, but here is where I am having problems - I want to cap the number of cols at 3 when the page scales up. Ideally, I would like to use `minmax` in the `repeat` directive like this:

`grid-template-columns: repeat( minmax(1, 3), minmax(300px, 1fr) );`

but of course this doesn't work. How can I limit repeat to 3 columns while still maintaining my downscale settings with `auto-fit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand correctly what you can do is set a media query for larger screens. Lets say you want to show a 3 column grid for screens over 992px you can use something like this

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px){
  .grid-container{
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}
```

Let me know if that helps you! check it here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Krzbmz

Comment: That would in fact work, thanks. What I am trying to determine though is if this solution is acceptable as the "css grid way" of how to handle it instead of a duct tape hack. If no one else chimes in with some unknown-to-me param for grid settings that solves this, then I'll use breakpoints. I'll wait another day or so to see.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can set a max-limit on the number of columns using `auto-fit` or `auto-fill`. By definition, they will create as many tracks as can fit in the container without overflowing:

> [§ 7.2.2.2. Repeat-to-fill: `auto-fill` and `auto-fit`
>   repetitions](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-repeat)
>
> When `auto-fill` [or `auto-fit`] is given as the repetition number ...
>   then the number of repetitions is the largest possible positive
>   integer that does not cause the grid to overflow its grid container.

And you can't set the *max* value of the `minmax()` function to 30%, because then you run into the same problem you had in your first example:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)
```

Namely, the column tracks become fixed on all screen sizes, and the layout is not responsive.

I understand that you're looking for a solution that doesn't require media queries. But if you want to use grid layout, I think media queries may be your best bet.

Otherwise, consider flex layout:

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wakyf3vL/2/)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 300px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 5px;
  border: 5px solid white;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item</div>
</div>
```

If you go the flex route, then read this post, too:

- [Targeting flex items on the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42176419/3597276)

Comment: It has potential but I also noticed a case where when cols are reduced to 2 the last child expands to 2x the items in the grid, or 100% the container. I would want all items equal width.

Comment: That's why I referred you to the post mentioned at the bottom.

Comment: No clean or easy solutions here using grid or flex. At least as far as I can see at the moment. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue by setting max-width to the grid. I had my columns as repeat(auto-fit, 150px). I wanted a max number of columns as x4 with 50px gap. So max-width of grid set to 800px.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). SO is not a Forum but a Q&A site. Do not post an answer to ask a simliar question. Open your own question!