# Specify number of columns and still have row wrap in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am supposed to use css grid with 12 columns. I also am supposed to have the tables stack in a column when the viewport becomes smaller.

Is this possible with CSS grid? I read for row wrap I have to use `auto-fill` or `auto-fit`. But I use either of those two, I can not specify 12 columns.

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.header {
  grid-column: 1 /12;
}

.table1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 7;
  grid-row: auto / span 20;
}

.table2,
.table3 {
  grid-column: 7/ 12;
  grid-row: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box header">header</div>
  <div class="box table1">table 1</div>


  <div class="box table2">table 2</div>
  <div class="box table3">table 3</div>

</div>
```

Comment: use media query and change the columns on small screens

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify a fixed number of tracks with `auto-fill` or `auto-fit`.

> [§ 7.2.2.2. Repeat-to-fill: `auto-fill` and `auto-fit`
> repetitions](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-repeat)
>
> When `auto-fill` or `auto-fit` is given as the repetition number, if the grid
> container has a definite size or max size in the relevant axis, then
> the number of repetitions is the largest possible positive integer
> that does not cause the grid to overflow its grid container.
>
> If any number of repetitions would overflow, then 1 repetition.

The best way to achieve your layout, considering the limitations of [the current (Level 1) version of CSS Grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/), is with **flexbox** ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3dge98wa/)), which comes with its own [set of limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42176419/3597276), or with the crude and inelegant power of good old-fashioned **media queries**.

Comment: hi, it would be good if you can take a look at this one :https://stackoverflow.com/q/54128973/8620333 . I am not really sure about my explanation, you can probably correct me or give a more accurate answer :)