# Is there a selector for first|last|n-item in a row with flex-wrap: wrap;?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

comrades.

I need to show a list of few elements with unknown width and number of elements, there a separators between items also. It can be few rows, or can not to be.

I use a flexboxed `<ul>` with *flex-wrap* and make separators with `<li>` `s *border-left*.
I need to hide separators of first item of each row if row was wrapped to few rows.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
li {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}
li:first-child { /* here i need something like ul:flex-row li:first-child */
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Does there exist the solution of this task with **css**?
Or only thing i can use is **js**, like `offset().top` changes of `<li>`s parsing and adding modifier-classname?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: CSS isn't a programming language, so there would be no way for it to determine the first `li` on a new row. You would have to create a new `ul` and target the first `li` of each `ul` instead of dynamically wrapping, or use JavaScript to determine the first `li` after the wrapping occurred.

Comment: Sure, css is not a programming language. But we still have `:first-child`, `:nth-child(n)`, and more other cool stuff.
As long as a task is dynamically-wrapping of the list -- i can't use new `<ul>`.

Comment: @MikePolo fair point, but keep in mind that `nth-child` type pseudo selectors are targetting DOM elements directly. I.e. if I target `nth-child`, the same element will be targeted regardless of any style rules that show or hide it. You can imagine it as if CSS rules target elements BEFORE any styles are actually applied to the document as a whole. There's no way to target an element based on it's response to a previous style. For example: I can't target all element with a red background - does that make sense/help? - also, have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42176419/6049581 Good luck!

Comment: Fair enough. So **js** is the only solution in this case, i guess. Thanks, Frits, and good luck to you too.