# Aligning items that are forced inside a cell via grid-area

Tags: css

Let's say I have structure like this:

```
parent
 -div_child1
 -div_child2
 -div_child3
 -div_child4
```

Where `parent` has a grid style like:

```css
grid-template-areas:
"a b"
"c c";
```

however, **the amount of children can differ and can be at least 3**, therefore, in order to fit the full content of child 3 in style like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t00sE.jpg

I had to force last row to have same-defined column names. The problem arises when there are more children. I cant put them into separate cells now so I put them all in `grid c` which leads to the overlapping issues I cant seems to find any way to solve. Honestly, I'd be just happy to make them respect each other width and that would be enough for me.

I sense there are 2 possible solutions:

- If there are more than 3 children - define more columns and place them in separate. This would work but then there is no way for me to make situation work with just 3 children since I can't assign child3 to multiple named `gird-areas` to take full row space nor I can hide them somehow inside that child codeblock so the 3rd cell can take remaining space of the row.
- There is a way to align multiple items inside a cell of a grid but. I never found any info on that.

**EXAMPLES:**
With 3 children: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G4QC3C4YA3HS
Same parent but with 4 children: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G4QC5VAA6J4E (overlapping issue)

*Remember:* I cannot change parent for different cases, its content/children autopopulated!

Relevant: [css grid, grid-area avoid items overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55528419/css-grid-grid-area-avoid-items-overlapping)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: please share some code to show what you've tried, so we could take a look at it.

Comment: @J.Sadi alright, done

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question is here but this sounds like a case for flexbox since the width of the "final" item is not known.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176419/targeting-flex-items-on-the-last-or-specific-row