# Is it possible to target the top row of items in a grid that uses auto-fill columns?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a css-grid container that uses auto-fill to layout the columns, using minmax to set the column size. Is there a way to target individual items inside the container that fall into whatever the top row happens to wind up being?

```css
ul {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}
```

Is there something in reality that works like the following?

```css
ul li:first-row {
      background: #000;
}
```

Comment: there is no such selecor but if it's only about background coloration there is other techniques to color only the first row

Comment: If you know how many grid items you'll have, then you can use media queries.

Comment: Similar concept: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42176419/3597276

Comment: I agree with the media query solution. If you're aware of how many children will be in a row at any given screen size, you could target with ``:nth-child`` inside of a media query.