# Using Bootstrap grid how do I make last items left align rather than spread over full width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4 to display a series of images using **row** and **col** classes

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <figure class="figure">
                    <a href="FixSongsReport00211_changesVarious Artists_Sounds of the Sixties 1960 Still Swinging.html">
                        <img src="../style/images/folder.jpg" class="figure-img" width="200" height="200">
                    </a>
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption">
                        Sounds of the Sixties 1960 Still Swinging
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <figure class="figure">
                    <a href="FixSongsReport00211_changesVarious Artists_Stage + Screen.html">
                        <img src="../style/images/folder.jpg" class="figure-img" width="200" height="200">
                    </a>
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption">
                        Stage + Screen
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that when we get to end of list so we have less images then could be fitted into last row they are spaced out to use the available space. If you see the screenshot I want the last two images to take the left hand of the screen rather than being spaced out.

How do I achieve that ?

[image]

Looks particulary bad when only have a couple of items

i.e

[image]

The answers suggesting grid worked for last line, but only if have multiple lines. I modifield the outer div to use grid by remving class and adding style style="display:grid;grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));grid-gap: 5px;".

This fixes the issue with the last row (1st image), however it has no effect when only has one row (2nd image), any ideas ?

The flexbox solutions seem to involve hardcoding various things, dont seem that they would work in the general case.

Comment: One row contains 12 columns, so using a _col-3_ should be resolved your problem

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo that would only work if users screen happens to accomodate 4 items, it could accomodate more or less.

Comment: @Paulie_D I modifield the outer div to use grid by remving class and adding style style="display:grid;grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));grid-gap: 5px;" . This fixes the issue with the last row (1st image), however it has no effect when only has one row (2nd image), any ideas ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Sounds like **another question** but CSS-Grid and auto-fit/fill don't act in the same way as flexbox does. the alignment is often quite different.

Comment: @Paulie_D you linked to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176419/targeting-flex-items-on-the-last-or-specific-row and the main answer there suggests using grid, so I have tried to implement that. I would prefer to use pure Bootstrap but the links for flexbox solutions in that answer all seem to be hacks.

Comment: @Paulie_D so if yo think grid is a bad idea Im not clear what yo think is actually the correct answer

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't use CSS-Grid (yet) so without it....I'm afraid hacks are what you have. Grid will work but it's a matter of choice as to whether you chose to use it.

Comment: Well the grid seems to work perfectly for Image1 as I have used it just not Image2 , can I amend it somehow to make it work for 2