# CSS Flexbox - How to align last row left or right while using justify-content: space-between

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using flex for aligning dynamic length of LIs. Everything is working fine but I am not sure how to align last row to left or right align while using flex's justify-content: space-between.

LIs length is dynamic and can be any of numbers e.g. 8, 9, 10... etc.

Comment: JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/xeqeloheme/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Use `ul::after { content: ""; flex: auto;}`

Comment: @Fanky, I am surprised how it is working! Thanks, as it can be a hack if we have fixed items. For dynamic elements it is also aligning last row if we have 3 elements in last row. Even if there are only 2 items in last row I would like to have equal margin b/w them as in earlier row elements :)

Comment: not sure I understand, but with this hack, you should have no margins of `li` to left and right, rather wrap the content like `<li><div>content</div></li>` and use padding on `li`. I've created a fiddle in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60420485/2095642) to the "duplicate" question

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you can't. That is what you're trying to do is not how the `justify-content: space-between` property works. It does exactly what you see it doing. Instead you could use `justify-content: flex-start` with nth item margining to achieve the layout you're looking for.

Don't forget to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the li style, otherwise you'll have to remove 3 pixels from the left/right margin on the middle items to account for your borders.

This will repeat consistently no matter how many items you add for the layout you have of rows of 3. If you want rows of 4, 5, etc. you only need to modify the widths and where you apply the margins. You can play around with various nth-child numbers to achieve whatever result you want.

Try this:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

li {
  width: calc(33.33% - 20px);
  border: 1px solid;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
li:nth-child(3n+2){
  margin: 0 30px 30px;
}
```