# How can I center flex-wrap rows while keeping the flex items left justified?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Something like this:

[image: flexbox example]

`justify-content: center;` gets me close, but this centers all the items in the flex container. I'd like to keep the items left-justified while centering the wrapped rows underneath those.

Comment: You can't., that's not the way flexbox works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176419/targeting-flex-items-on-the-last-or-specific-row

Comment: Ah that's too bad. Would CSS grid be an option?

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you have fixed/known widths for the container itself, or for the flex items, you could simulate this. You just need to contain the flex-container in another element and then left-align it in some way. Then you can center justify the flex items.

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/aaronburrows/pen/ExVoyWv)

```css
ul {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
li {
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 20px);
  height: 80px;
  background: #333;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try `margin: 0 auto;` in the  child  element

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 120px; /* screen width  */

}

.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Since you haven't provided any code, this is one of the solutions, but in this case you need to store top and bottom rows in separate divs:

```css
        .item{
            min-width:45%;
            min-height: 80px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            background-color: black;
        }
        .top-row,.bottom-row{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            width: 30%;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
        }
        .bottom-row{
            justify-content: center;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="top-row">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-row">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
```