# how to make flex-direction row responsive

Tags: css, mobile, flexbox, responsive

I'm using this css for a-z list

```
#a-z {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
ul#a-z li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #282c39;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-left: 2px solid #1d1b24;
}
```

html

```
<ul id="a-z">
<li class="active" data-letter="#">#</li>
<li class="active" data-letter=a>a</li>
<li class="active" data-letter=b>b</li>
<li class="active" data-letter=c>c</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

I would like to make it responsive and adaptable to mobile devices, is it possible to find a solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try specifying ```#a-z``` with ```flex-wrap:wrap;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only you showed the full content of your HTML but you can wrap your flex item when the container width can't fit the flex children using
`flex-wrap:wrap;` property

Comment: bad result, first line is good, second line items are too big https://prnt.sc/uhuq9f

Comment: @fr0zen, https://stackoverflow.com/q/42176419/3597276