# Sizing and Arrangement of Items with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to display a set of boxes listing the amenities available at a hotel. The number of boxes varies with each hotel. I want to use Flexbox to fill the width of the page but keep all the boxes the same size.

As a typical example I might have say 13 boxes, and with a normal sized browser window that will display 5 boxes in a row. I can use min-width and flex-grow to control the top two rows which are full, but then the third row with only 3 boxes stretches those boxes across the whole width. Instead I want those boxes to be the same width as the others above.

Is this even possible?

```css
.amenity-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 96%;
  position: relative
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center
}

.amenity {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid #007aba;
  color: #007aba;
  padding: .4em .25em .25em;
  min-width: 14.5em;
  margin: 0 .5em .5em 0;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div class="amenity-wrapper">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="amenity"><i class="icon-<?php echo $key ?>"></i><span><?php echo $value ?></span></div>
    
    <div class="amenity"><i class="icon-<?php echo $key ?>"></i><span><?php echo $value ?></span></div>
    
    <div class="amenity"><i class="icon-<?php echo $key ?>"></i><span><?php echo $value ?></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For `flexbox` I always look at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/  .

Comment: It is not possible to do so using flexbox. See [Sizing flex items on the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176419/sizing-flex-items-on-the-last-row)

Comment: However, it can be done easily using `grid`. In your case it's `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(14.5em, 1fr));`

Comment: Thank you @SyndRain. The second link you gave did solve my problem. I didn't want to use Grid as I am modifying a large website that currently uses Flexbox so I wanted to stick with that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem was to add hidden boxes that have width but no visibility or height. As the page could have 9 boxes on a row if the browser is full screen on a big monitor, I had to include 8 hidden boxes. That doesn't matter though because the zero height means they don't change the page layout in any other way.

```css
.amenity-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 96%;
  position: relative
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center
}

.amenity {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid #007aba;
  color: #007aba;
  padding: .4em .25em .25em;
  min-width: 14.5em;
  margin: 0 .5em .5em 0;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden
}

.amenity.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="amenity-wrapper">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="amenity"><i class="icon-<?php echo $key ?>"></i><span><?php echo $value ?></span></div>
    
    <div class="amenity"><i class="icon-<?php echo $key ?>"></i><span><?php echo $value ?></span></div>
    
    <div class="amenity"><i class="icon-<?php echo $key ?>"></i><span><?php echo $value ?></span></div>
    
    <div class="amenity hidden"></div>
    <div class="amenity hidden"></div>
    <div class="amenity hidden"></div>
    <div class="amenity hidden"></div>
    <div class="amenity hidden"></div>
    <div class="amenity hidden"></div>
    <div class="amenity hidden"></div>
    <div class="amenity hidden"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Extra markup solely for formatting is rarely the best solution.

Comment: I thought this was the solution, but then discovered that it didn't work well with Chrome (at least, not with the other CSS I was using). While all the boxes were coming up the same size in Safari, they came out random widths in Chrome.
So my final solution was to follow another suggestion and use Grid. I hadn't ever used it before but it was dead simple and did what I wanted.